# Grouping data by week in an Excel pivot table which has distinct count

Tags: excel, pivot-table, grouping, distinct-values

My raw data looks like this: [raw_data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UbSIM.jpg)

I want to group this data by week, showing the number of distinct shows viewed by each viewer every week.
The data should look like this. [ExpectedOutput](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxRzD.jpg)

I've created a pivot table of my raw data, which looks like this: [Pivot1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FXjUI.jpg)

When creating the pivot table, I selected 'Add this data to the data model' because I want a distinct count of shows viewed, and that is the only way to make the distinct count option available. Unfortunately, selecting the data model options limits the available grouping options as you cannot group by week.

So, I tried to create a pivot of my pivot, without adding the data to the data model to see if that would work but it didn't, as the column headers are not dates, so the grouping function is disabled.

I'm really stuck on this problem so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Power Query`, available in Excel 2010+, is useful for creating these kinds of reports.

*(I tried working with the Pivot Table, but could not get the column headers to show up as you preferred, and also **properly sorted.**)*

To use Power Query, depending on your version of Excel, go to the Data Tab and select Get & Transform from Table/Range (or the equivalent in pre-2016 versions).

Then:

- Convert the Date/Time column to just dates
- Add a column for start of the week and format it `dd/MM/yyyy`

[image]

- Add a column for start of the week + 6 days and format it `dd/MM/yyyy`

[image]

- Merge the wkStart and wkEnd columns with "`-`" as the separator.
- Remove the now unneeded columns
- `Group` by week and Viewer ID, Aggregating by unique count of rows

[image]

- Pivot on week

[image]

**Voila!**

[image]

All of the above can be done from the UI of Power Query.  Below is the generated M-Code.

If you turn your data into a **Table**, you can just paste the M-Code into the PQ Editor, and change the Table Name in the second line to the real name of your table.

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Viewer ID", Int64.Type}, {"DatTime", type date}, {"ShowID", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "wkStart", each Date.ToText(Date.StartOfWeek([DatTime],Day.Monday),"dd/MM/yyyy")),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "wkEnd", each Date.ToText(Date.AddDays(Date.StartOfWeek([DatTime],Day.Monday),6),"dd/MM/yyyy")),
    #"Inserted Merged Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom1", "Week", each Text.Combine({[wkStart], [wkEnd]}, " - "), type text),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Inserted Merged Column",{"wkStart", "wkEnd", "DatTime"}),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Removed Columns", {"Week", "Viewer ID"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(Table.Distinct(_)), Int64.Type}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(#"Grouped Rows", List.Distinct(#"Grouped Rows"[Week]), "Week", "Count", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

Comment: @ScarlettLouis Glad to help. I'm just learning the ins and outs of PQ. It can do many things that I'm still trying to figure out.

Comment: I'm not sure why my previous comment disappeared. Weird. But anyway, thank you again. You saved me hours.